# Add attribute to existing Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, customization, parameter

I have an existing shortcode (from a plugin) and I would like to add a new attribute or parameter to this shortcode.

The shortcode looks like this:

```
[my_shortcode_from_plugin_xyz posts="5" autoplay="true"]
```

Is it possible to add a new attribute like `=> url="https://lorem.de"?`

This is working, but I can't get the attribute from the shortcode itself:

```
[my_shortcode_from_plugin_xyz posts="5" autoplay="true" url="https://lorem.de"]

function do_something( $atts ) {      
    $atts['siteurl'] = '';

return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_recent_post_slider', 'do_something', 10, 3 );
```

I also tried to set the defaults like this:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( [
    'siteurl' => '',
  ], $atts  );
```

The plugIn code to create the shortcode:

```
function wprpsp_recent_post_slider( $atts, $content = null ) {


$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'post_type'             => 'post',
    'taxonomy'              => 'category',
    'limit'                 => 20,
    'category'              => '',
    'include_cat_child'     => 'true',
    'design'                => 'design-1',
    'show_date'             => 'true',
    'show_category_name'    => 'true',
    'show_content'          => 'true',
    'show_author'           => 'true',
    'content_words_limit'   => 20,
    'fade'                  => 'false',
    'content_tail'          => '...',
    'dots'                  => 'true',
    'arrows'                => 'true',
    'autoplay'              => 'true',
    'autoplay_interval'     => 3000,
    'speed'                 => 600,
    'loop'                  => 'true',
    'nav_slides'            => 4,
    'rtl'                   => '',
    'link_target'           => 'self',
    'show_read_more'        => 'true',
    'read_more_text'        => '',
    'order'                 => 'DESC',
    'orderby'               => 'date',
    'exclude_cat'           => array(),
    'hide_post'             => array(),
    'posts'                 => array(),
    'include_author'        => array(),
    'exclude_author'        => array(),
    'slider_height'         => '',
    'sticky_posts'          => 'false',
    'image_size'            => 'full',
    'image_fit'             => 'true',
    'query_offset'          => '',
    'extra_class'           => '',
    ), $atts, 'recent_post_slider');

$supported_post_types           = wprpsp_get_option( 'post_types',array() );
    $shortcode_designs              = wprpsp_recent_post_slider_designs();
    $atts['content_tail']           = html_entity_decode( $atts['content_tail'] );
    $atts['post_type']              = ( !empty( $atts['post_type'] ) && in_array( $atts['post_type'], $supported_post_types ) ) ? $atts['post_type'] : 'post';
    $atts['taxonomy']               = ( !empty( $atts['taxonomy'] ) )               ? $atts['taxonomy']                             : 'category';
    $atts['limit']                  = !empty( $atts['limit'] )                      ? $atts['limit']                                : 20;
    $atts['category']               = ( !empty( $atts['category'] ) )               ? explode( ',',$atts['category'] )              : '';
    $atts['include_cat_child']      = ( $atts['include_cat_child'] == 'false' )     ? false                                         : true;
    $atts['design']                 = ( $atts['design'] && ( array_key_exists( trim( $atts['design'] ), $shortcode_designs ) ) ) ? trim( $atts['design'] ) : 'design-1';
    $atts['show_date']              = ( $atts['show_date'] == 'false' )             ? 0                                             : 1;
    $atts['show_category_name']     = ( $atts['show_category_name'] == 'false' )    ? 0                                             : 1;
    $atts['show_content']           = ( $atts['show_content'] == 'false' )          ? 0                                             : 1;
    $atts['show_author']            = ( $atts['show_author'] == 'false' )           ? 0                                             : 1;
    $atts['content_words_limit']    = !empty( $atts['content_words_limit'] )        ? $atts['content_words_limit']                  : 20;
    $atts['fade']                   = ( $atts['fade'] == 'false' )                  ? 'false'                                       : 'true';
    $atts['dots']                   = ( $atts['dots'] == 'false' )                  ? 'false'                                       : 'true';
    $atts['arrows']                 = ( $atts['arrows'] == 'false' )                ? 'false'                                       : 'true';
    $atts['autoplay']               = ( $atts['autoplay'] == 'false' )              ? 'false'                                       : 'true';
    $atts['autoplay_interval']      = !empty( $atts['autoplay_interval'] )          ? $atts['autoplay_interval']                    : 3000;
    $atts['speed']                  = !empty( $atts['speed'] )                      ? $atts['speed']                                : 600;
    $atts['infinite']               = ( $atts['loop'] == 'true' )                   ? 'true'                                        : 'false';
    $atts['nav_slides']             = !empty( $atts['nav_slides'] )                 ? $atts['nav_slides']                           : 4;
    $atts['link_target']            = ( $atts['link_target'] == 'blank')            ? '_blank'                                      : '_self';
    $atts['show_read_more']         = ( $atts['show_read_more'] == 'false' )        ? 0                                             : 1;
    $atts['order']                  = (strtolower( $atts['order'] ) == 'asc' )      ? 'ASC'                                         : 'DESC';
    $atts['orderby']                = !empty( $atts['orderby'] )                    ? $atts['orderby']                              : 'date';
    $atts['exclude_cat']            = !empty( $atts['exclude_cat'] )                ? explode( ',', $atts['exclude_cat'] )          : array();
    $atts['hide_post']              = !empty( $atts['hide_post'] )                  ? explode( ',', $atts['hide_post'] )            : array();
    $atts['posts']                  = !empty( $atts['posts'] )                      ? explode( ',', $atts['posts'] )                : array();
    $atts['include_author']         = !empty( $atts['include_author'] )             ? explode( ',', $atts['include_author'] )       : array();
    $atts['exclude_author']         = !empty( $atts['exclude_author'] )             ? explode( ',', $atts['exclude_author'] )       : array();
    $atts['read_more_text']         = !empty( $atts['read_more_text'] )             ? $atts['read_more_text']                       : __('Read More', 'wp-responsive-recent-post-slider');
    $atts['slider_height']          = ( !empty( $atts['slider_height'] ) )          ? $atts['slider_height']                        : '';
    $atts['slider_height_css']      = ( !empty( $atts['slider_height'] ) )          ? "style='height:{$atts['slider_height']}px;'"  : '';
    $atts['sticky_posts']           = ( $atts['sticky_posts'] == 'true' )           ? false                                         : true;
    $atts['image_size']             = !empty( $atts['image_size'] )                 ? $atts['image_size']                           : 'full';
    $atts['image_fit']              = ( $atts['image_fit'] == 'false' )             ? 0                                             : 1;
    $atts['query_offset']           = !empty( $atts['query_offset'] )               ? $atts['query_offset']                         : null;
    $atts['extra_class']            = wprpsp_pro_sanitize_html_classes( $atts['extra_class'] );

    // Extract Shortcode Var
    extract($atts);
```

Puhh, I'm completely stuck ...

BR, P

Comment: If you want to add a new attribute to a shortcode, surely you'd need to change the code of the actual shortcode to do anything with it. At that point you might as well just copy the shortcode and create a new one.

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie for your fast answer!